# Replicating this analog laser diode driver

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, analog, laser

I'm working on an RGB show laser and currently am figuring out what to do for the laser drivers, as they need to be modulated with a 0-5 V analog signal. There are ones for purchase but are pretty expensive relative to the somewhat simple an inexpensive parts. [Here](http://www.die4laser.com/dvd-rec/Die4Drive_files/Die4DriveRev1-2.pdf) is a link to a pdf schematic of one of these.

[image]

I understand for the most part how it works. It uses a MOSFET in the linear region to control the output current, and uses an opamp and a sense resistor to control the gate voltage of the MOSFET. It has two potentiometers, one to control the maximum current limit and one to control the threshold current for the laser diode, so you can have 0 V input be just below laser emission, and 5 V at your maximum current.

I want to recreate this but I don't have the same exact MOSFET and opamp.  I have similar ones on hand. I wanted to ask specifically how the opamp configuration works, and what the range setting resistors do. How can I use this to design my own version that suits my needs?

Comment: What is the max laser operating current and lasing threshold current? This way of doing it is decent. But what you really want to do is servo the intensity of the laser with the analog signal. Do you have any optical feedback from the laser? This is typically a photodiode that picks off part of the working beam.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything special that's required of the op-amp or the MOSFET in this circuit, so chances are good that you can get it to work with any op-amp and any MOSFET as long you pay attention to the usual parameters that matter for op-amps and MOSFETs (e.g. max power dissipation). But I suppose you know absolutely nothing about how this circuit works or you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @MOSFET I don't need the analog signal and the optical output power to be proportional, I just need it so that 0V is off, 5V is on, and in between is fine. I just don't understand how the range resistor values and some of the other resistor values with the opamp were chosen.

Comment: @user253751 I understand the basics of how opamps work and how this circuit works, it just uses a non inverting amplifier and uses the sense resistor voltage for the noninverting input. I just was asking how some of the resistor values are calculated. For example the resistors R1 through R8.

Comment: R4,5,8 are just a crude trimmer resistor that you can adjust in binary by setting links. The node in between R4-8 is a summing junction. The offset trimmer lets current in, the range-setting links let current out, and R6 lets current in from the input (the amount also depends on R1). If you don't need yours to be adjustable, you don't need so many resistors. If you can adjust the range and offset *in software*, you don't need any at all.

Comment: @lostbeam488 Pretty much all the resistors were chosen for biasing and ranging the DC operating points. The exception is R7, R9 and R11. Which I provide insight on those in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole circuit is a voltage-controlled current sink. Let's start by simplifying this circuit down:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffCYxQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I believe this to be the bare minimum to perform the DC analysis. But first, let me justify why I eliminated components and why they're not important (for now):

- D1 just a dual protection diode to keep the input between the power rails
- R7 and C1 form a low-pass filter for the soft-start. Presumably this is to supress laser output during turn-on transients. Not needed for analysis and the circuit functions without it.
- R11 and C2 are actually needed in reality to stabilize the op-amp by adding a pole to compensate for the MOSFET gate capacitance. They also reduce the bandwidth to eliminate any overshoot that might damage the laser by setpoint step changes (the intent is an overdamped response as to not "spike" the laser). Again, R11 and C2 have nothing to do with the dc operating points.
- C3 and C4 are just filtering caps to stabilize the power supply for the laser.
- D2 - Protection diodes for protecting the actual laser diode.
- R10 - voltage sample point to monitor current. This is likely for initial setup where a dummy load is placed where the real laser would go to set the gain resistors so the real laser doesn't get destroyed by careless gain setting.
- R4, R5, and R8 change the overall gain, specifically, it will set a nominal transconductance range (A/V) based on a spreadsheet reference. R4 represents just one of the settings.

So without going through every design detail (or the math unless requested by popular demand), the methodology is as follows:

The sense resistor first gets sized based on the largest current that the circuit will be assumed to handle. 1 ohm is used in this design implies absolute max current could be 5A (5V/1ohm). The reality is it's even less than that because the MOSFET drops negligible voltage (while saturated) and the forward voltage drop of the diode has to be considered. But 5 volts will be the upper limit anyway. So a MOSFET has to be chosen to handle this 5A current. Since we only have 5V rails the MOSFET will need a relatively low Vgs threshold voltage. This in contrast to SMPS where its common to slam the transistors back and forth between cutoff and saturation with gate voltages of 10-15V.

R9 is not that important. It helps isolate the capacitive loading of the MOSFET gate to the opamp output (op-amps don't like capacitive loads so R9 "tricks" the op-amp into thinking it's driving a resistive load (kind of). It adds stability at the expense of response time.

At this point, the power stage is understood. The transfer function is going to be 1V/A. In other words, the opamp is going to modulate the gate voltage in such a way that 1A will flow through the laser for every volt seen on the non-inverting input (pin 3).

With that information known, the front-end resistor network has to be tailored for the input signal range and to match the desired electrical laser characteristics of the laser knowing you are going to give the laser 1A/V of juice.

This procedure is as follows. The gain shall be set to zero. This results in R6 and R4, in parallel, pulling the non-inverting input to ground. So at gain zero, that's 2.13k.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsbnWD.png)</sup>

The offset pot does just that - it provides an offset that is "summed" with the input pot. The reason for this pot is bias some current through the laser to get it to operate within its linear operating regime so that modulating the input signal doesn't cause abrupt changes in laser output do this "crossover" region where the intensity is highly non-linear.

This "crossover" point is called the lasing threshold and it is defined as the minimum current need to stabilize the laser (strictly speaking, it's the point in which the gains equal the losses inside the laser resonator). What that means is any current below this current, no laser light is produced (maybe some dim pump energy).

So, you can set the offset pot to be either right below this point (if you need "no output" when your signal is zero) or, you can set it right above this point so that you can keep the laser operating in it's linear region the whole time. This will depend on what you are really trying to do.

The final thing to do, is apply the maximum input voltage that your upstream controller is expected to produce and turn the gain pot up until the laser is at it's max operating point (maybe a little less to be safe). If you "run out" of gain and the gain pot maxes out, your range setting resistor is too low of value. Repeat the setup from the offset pot using a high value "range setting" resistor.

The resistor array that you inquire about is just a fancy summing amplifier - it has selectable resistors instead of just one that you will typically see in "summing amplifier circuits". They just add flexibility for the user to use multiple lasers with different current requirements.

After all that is understood, you can put back the option soft start (R7 and C1), and the origin-pole R11 and C2 for stability. And of course the protection and filtering components.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was such a great explanation.

Comment: I have a quick question about it, if the forward voltage of my diode exceeds 5V, can I just instead supply, say, 12V to the LDA? Would this work while still keeping the 5V analog signal?

Comment: @lostbeam488 Yes you can do that. Everything else stays the same. But you're going to have to calculate power losses in the MOSFET for thermal management. Also, you want to make sure your not exceeding Vrb of D2. This design is basically "open drain" so the laser PS can be almost anything the transistor can handle.

Comment: i've constructed the circuit to a tee, I've triple checked it, replaced components, but even when the pots are both at 0V the ouput acts as a short circuit, why would this be? I'm even using a mosfet with very similar characteristics.

Comment: @lostbeam488 Disconnect the gate and tie it to ground. Still SC? The MOSFET is shorted. No? Start making measurements from the MOSFET back. What is the Vgs (op-amp output)? Then measure the opamp inputs.

Comment: @lostbeam488 I think I know what the problem is - your opamp's input(s) are falling outside the acceptable common-mode range. What you are probably seeing is a phenomenon called "phase-reversal". What you need to do, is tweak the pots so that you get at least 1.5V or a little more on the inputs. Or, it would be better to use an op-amp that has "rail-to-rail" inputs and no phase-reversal.

Comment: sorry I didn’t respond sooner, it turned out that the lm741 I used couldn’t do rail to rail, I replaced it with an mcp6002 I ripped off an old voltmeter and it works perfectly, thank you for all of the help and knowledge!